# Observable and nested list in object

Tags: java, observable, rx-java2

I am doing my first steps with RxJava und Retrofit. I have a rest API which returns an `Observable<Department>`. The class `Department` has a nested list of `Team` objects. How can I get an `Observable<Team>` which delivers all teams of the nested list from the `Observable<Department>`?

I tried playing around with `map()`and `switchMap()` but I still can't get the desired `Observable<Team>`.

My idea is to subscribe to the `Observable<Team>` and for every delivered team I trigger some update logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a pipeline using map to get the inner values and then flatMapIterable to unwrap the arrays.

Suppose `dept$` is your `Observable<Department>`

```
dept$
  .map(d -> d.getTeam())
  .flatMapIterable(teamArr -> teamArr)
  .doOnNext(System.out::println)
  .subscribe();
```